# react useState doesn't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I have a table with checkboxes and I want to save selected checkboxes' ids in state. So here's my code.

Input looks like this (I use coreui so this is the inside of a table's scopedSlots):

```
selected: (item) => {
 return (
  <td style={{ width: '40px' }}>
   <CInputCheckbox
     className="mx-auto"
     id={item.id}
     onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e)}
   />
  </td>
);}
```

And this is the rest:

```
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

const handleSelect = (e) => {
  const id = e.target.id;
  const index = selectedRows.indexOf(id);
  const rows = [...selectedRows];
  if (index === -1) {
    rows.push(id);
  } else {
    rows.split(index, 1);
  }
  setSelectedRows(rows);
};
```

And the weirdest thing happens - in the chrome's react devtools I see that the first id is being added to the selectedRows array and then when I select another row - the previous item in the array is being overwritten. When i console.log my selectedRows array it shows empty array always (even if I see in the devtools that there's one item). I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Where are you logging at? Please give us a reproducible example of code that generates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot of information to work with in your question, so I had to make many assumptions about how are they suppose to work, but this is what I got so far:

- the *handleSelect* function has a little error when it comes to removing items from the list, your function is using split but I think what you meant was slice
- I think the scopes of *handleSelect* and `const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);`  are wrong. For what I can see, they are at the same level of **selected** component, which will fail as they will only be able to keep track of one selected component at the time, and I think you are needing to keep track of multiple **selected** components.

Here is a working version of what I think you are trying to do

https://codepen.io/richard-unal/pen/eYWXXOo?editors=1111

If you need clarification on something, please let me know, I'm aware that I'm not the best explainer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That was exactly what I was trying to do and my code looks very similar (with one difference that CInputCheckbox is in my case a component from a library coreui). Changing split to slice didn't help and I still couldn't get it to work.
So I changed my selectedRows to an array of objects looking something like this:
[ { id: 1, value: false }, { id: 2, value: false } ]
and when user clicks checkbox I change value to true / false. And that finally worked for me.
Anywas thank you so much for your time and help!